# Beginner chef in need of advice

Tags: slow-cooking, budget-cooking, outdoor-cooking, foil-cooking

I have little experience and little money. I would like to know beginner recipes that are well rounded. Sorry if this is in the wrong place, still pretty new.

Comment: Yup...wrong place for recipe requests.  Sorry, it's not what we do here.

Comment: How do I Remove this question . This app is weird

Comment: After ramen or Mac and cheese, the first big challenge is the hamburger, followed by the cheeseburger. Eggs, scrambled then over easy, then omelettes. You lack the power to delete the question 48102. You need 10 or 100 points or something to do that. Keep coming back and the obstacles will go away. It's worth it because there's a lot of good cooking tips here.

Comment: Try the YouTube series ["Basics with Babish"](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLopY4n17t8RD-xx0UdVqemiSa0sRfyX19)

Comment: Also Chef John's youtube series is very beginner-friendly.

Comment: @FuzzyChef Chef John is the biz, he’s probably more easily found by searching for “Food Wishes” than by his name, but the videos are only half the story, the ingredients and more info are always in his [Blog](https://foodwishes.blogspot.co.uk/?m=1)

Comment: Striving for well roundedness could make you boring - pick a cuisine/style you LOVE eating and start practicing ....